# How to post data from a php file to another php file to add the data to database without using ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a php file (todo.php & todo.js) which collects some data from user and uses ajax to post the collected data to another php file (add.php) to be added to database . My issue is that I don't want to use ajax to post the data to the second php file (add.php). How do I change this. I have extracted the codes and shown below

//todo.js is called from todo.php to validate new todoEntry

```
function addToDo(){
    var descField = document.getElementById('nDesc');
    var percField = document.getElementById('nPerc');

    if( !validateField(descField) ){
        alert("Description " + errorMessage);
        return;
    }
    if( !validatePercentField(percField) ){
        alert("Percentage " + errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    //use ajax to post new entries to add.php which will add them
    ajaxCall(encodeURI('add.php?description=' + descField.value  
           + '&percentage=' + percField.value), function(response){
        if( response.status == 200 ){
            if( response.responseText.toString().indexOf
        ("success") != -1 ){
                //clear values
                descField.value = "";
                percField.value = "";

                //refresh table
                fetchToDo();
            }
            else
                alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
    }

     From add.php:
    <?php
    session_start();

    if( !isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
        die("Your Session has expired. Please re-login to continue");
    }

    //get required data
    $description = trim(isset($_GET['description']) ? urldecode($_GET   
        ['description']) : "");
    $percentage = trim(isset($_GET['percentage']) ? urldecode($_GET
        ['percentage']) : "");

    //validate data
    if( empty($description) || empty($percentage) ){
        die("All fields are required!");
    }

    //connect to database
    include('connect.php');

    //insert data
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO todo_entry VALUES (NULL, ?, NOW 
        (), NOW(), ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $_SESSION['username'], $description,
         $percentage);
    $stmt->execute();

    if( $stmt->affected_rows > 0 ){
        $stmt->close();
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "An Error Occured: " . $stmt->error;
        $stmt->close();
    }

    //close database
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: create a form give action to second page and method = post. you will get all data on second page in $_POST.

Comment: There is a serious draw back in this logic. Indeed, you are talking about very basic topic that you 100% know. What you are talking about is a form functionality. As @anantkumarsingh said exactly. Life is more easier than your desired work flow suppose.

Comment: Yes, and if you don't want load another page using a form, Ajax is the only option here.

Answer (score 1):

cURL is to PHP as AJAX is to JS. If you want to call one script from another directly from PHP without requiring the broswer to make additional requests to the server, you can use cURL. Here's a simple function.

```
/*
 * Makes an HTTP request via GET or POST, and can download a file
 * @returns - Returns the response of the request
 * @param $url - The URL to request, including any GET parameters
 * @param $params - An array of POST values to send
 * @param $filename - If provided, the response will be saved to the 
 *    specified filename
 */
function request($url, $params = array(), $filename = "") {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlOpts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        // Set Useragent
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) 
                    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
        // Don't validate SSL 
        // This is to prevent possible errors with self-signed certs
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    );
    if(!empty($filename)){
        // If $filename exists, save content to file
        $file2 = fopen($filename,'w+') 
            or die("Error[".__FILE__.":".__LINE__."] 
                    Could not open file: $filename");
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_FILE] = $file2;
    }
    if (!empty($params)) {
        // If POST values are given, send that shit too
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    // If there was an error, show it
    if (curl_error($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    if(!empty($filename)) fclose($file2);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: If the 2 PHP files are on the same server (the OP didn't tell but it looks like it since there's nothing before the 'add.php' current ajax URL), a simple `include()` of the second one would do the job without stressing the http server for nothing ;-)

Comment: His current solution is AJAX based, meaning the script is expecting certain post/get values. Using an include would require him to rewrite the script as those values wouldn't be present. But I agree that if possible, including it would be a better solution.

Comment: Changing the variables names in add.php would still be quicker than implementing an overkill curl approach ;-) Btw, you could still declare any `$_POST` or `$_GET` values in the script that would include add.php if you really don't want to change it and keep some kind of dual solution where add.php can be included or posted to.

Comment: @Capsule, like I said, if that's a reasonable solution then I fully agree it's a better one, but it may or may not be as simple as you imply. What if add.php is used in other places and outputs a bunch of XML or JSON. Or what if like you said, it's on another server. It really depends.

Comment: Yes but that's a lot of ifs. This is apparently not the case and the OP obviously has no idea what he's doing (no offense, everybody's been a beginner at some point) so let's not make him think curl is the answer to everything. But don't get me wrong. In another context/more complex environment, yes, definitely a good answer!

Comment: the 2 files are actually on the same server